# pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.rock.gota Error: Unknown option: --user

Tags: android

Yesterday I worked with an android tablet and everything works. But now when I'm using `pm uninstall -k --user 0 com.rock.gota`
I'm getting this message: `Error: Unknown option: --user`

Comment: did you try `pm uninstall  com.rock.gota` if it is shell command

Comment: it prints: `failure`

Answer (score -3):

The package `com.rock.gota` is a system app and it can't be uninstalled without system privilege. Please note that it handles Over the Air updates(OTA) for your phone. So removing that app will stop updates to your phone.

Comment: It is not a system app, it is malware. https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/141773/how-can-i-stop-adverts-from-system-update-from-showing-up-on-my-lockscreen-on

Comment: It's Virus Application. in "top" this application uses 45% of my CPU! I deleted it by using of root.